# How to get location and page no of pdf form field with browser js library

Tags: javascript, pdf, browser

I am using https://pdf-lib.js.org/ pdf-lib javascript library in browser for manipulating pdf form fields. I could not manage to find location and page number of a pdf form field with their api. Can anyone suggest any other js for browser library with which I can do it?

Comment: Please be aware that a PDF AcroForm Field is technically not part of a page. Instead, if a Field is on displayed on a page, it is represented by a Widget type Annotation. Annotations are always part of a single page. However, also note that a single Field could be represented by multiple Widget Annotations, which could be on different pages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I've found the location and page:

```
var doc = await PDFDocument.load(arraybuffer); //Get the pdf
var image = doc.embedPng(imageBytes); // Just for the demonstration...
for (var field of doc.getForm().getFields()) { // Get all acroform fields.
    var page = doc.findPageForAnnotationRef(field.ref); // Get field's page object;
    for (var widget of field.acroField.getWidgets()) { // Get all of the field widgets (which include it's locations)
        page.drawImage(image, widget.Rect().asRectangle()); // Using the page object and widget's rectangle object to draw the image in a specific location and page
    }
}
```

The `widget.Rect().asRectangle()` return an object with `x`,`y`,`width` and `height` properties.

The field's `ref` property is the field's unique identifier in the pdf which is used to find the object's page.

Comment: I think the question is just the page number. I can't seem to get the page number from PDFField or PDFPage refs.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so adding to Mr Wild's answer, to get the page number, get all the pages and the PDFPage of your field, then find the PDFPage.ref.tag of your fields page in the array of all pages, and add 1

```
const field = <your PDFField>

const pages = pdfDoc.getPages()

const fieldPage = pdfDoc.findPageForAnnotationRef(field.ref)

const fieldPageNum = pageArray.findIndex(page => page.ref.tag === fieldPage.ref.tag) + 1
```